# Error with tweepy library: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to create a simple program that will allow me to get all the twits where a specific user is mentioned. When executing the code I received the error response: 401 Unauthorized

The project permissions are set to read/write and DM, additionally I have regenerated the API keys.

If someone can tell me where else can be the problem I would be very grateful.

Anyway I am going to attach the code to verify that it is not a problem of a function call.

This is what I have so far:

```python
access_token = "XXXXXXX" # Access Token 
access_token_secret = "XXXXXXX" # Access Token Secret
consumer_key = "XXXXXXX" # API Key
consumer_secret = "XXXXXXX" # API Key Secret

client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=consumer_key, 
    consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
    access_token=access_token, 
    access_token_secret=access_token_secret
)

# Autenticación con la API de Twitter y creación del objeto API
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

max_tweets = 50
query = 'Iberia'

searched_tweets = client.search_all_tweets(query=query, max_results=max_tweets)

print(searched_tweets)
```

Comment: _"I am trying to create a simple program that will allow me to get all the twits where a specific user is mentioned."_ That will require one of the paid access tiers: _Basic_ for a "recent" search and _Pro_ for a "full history" search.